# How to keep API keys secret when using client side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, client-side

For example, check out this [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198/) plugin.

In the client side the API key is clearly visible. What is stopping another user from obtaining this key and using this feature on a different site?

I figured a very naive implementation would be to check the domain the request comes from but things like this are easy to fake.

If I were to create something similar, how would I go about securing the authentication process?

I want as much of this work to be client side, though some form of server authentication will be required surely? Any links or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256305/how-does-google-maps-secure-their-api-key-how-to-make-something-similar) about API keys that I found useful.

Comment: Have you looked at twitter's @anywhere? The API key is open, but they use other information /secret to test the data

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In three words: server-side validation. FB itself will throw an error when you use a key that's incorrect for the given site. The API key is not supposed to be secret (as opposed to the secret key).

Comment: I'm guessing in that case the api key will change for every single request right?

Comment: @Finglas: No. Why should it? The API key identifies your application, and that is tied to a single domain; if you use it on another domain, the API key won't match when it's checked on FB via AJAX and the UI won't load.

Comment: That's what I'm getting at. How can we trust the domain, if I registered site A, what's stopping me from making site B using the same key but bodging the headers prior to sending a request?

Comment: @Finglas: How exactly do you bodge the headers? They are not sent by your server, but by the user's browser.

Comment: Things such as Firebug/tamper data like tools etc... Despite this an API key sounds like it will do the job. An interesting question of the same topic can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256305/how-does-google-maps-secure-their-api-key-how-to-make-something-similar

Comment: @Finglas: Yes, I'm aware that HTTP is simple to modify in transfer, but that will only help you to pretend that a POST happened *from the legitimate domain*, accomplishing nothing for the new domain; furthermore, that will only help *you* - I posit that the other domain's users aren't interested in messing with their HTTP traffic.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the advice. You've pointed me in the right direction for what I need.

Comment: @Piskvor Is there any validation mechanism you would recommend?

Comment: @Bugs: This didn't exist when the question was written, and might be aimed at a different use-case, but see https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this myself, but I know that the kind of attack you are worried about is called Cross-site Request Forgery (CSRF). The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) on that gives some hints on how to prevent it.

Comment: That should be the title of this question. `"How to prevent Cross-site Request Forgery?"`

Comment: @mr5 If "Preventing CSRF" were the title, people like me who don't know the name wouldn't find the question

Comment: @Eponymous Well, you are correct! I can't remember why I wrote this stupid comment. Just ignore it. lol