# React, API keys and intermediary services

Tags: reactjs

I am kind of new to React, so this might be just lack of experience, but I don't seem to find any answer to my question:
I have a react app, where I need to subscribe to a push notification channel. Messages are delivered through PubNub, and in order to connect I need to supply a subscribe and a publish key to the message server. Now, I know it is not a good practice to store secrets in a react app, and they should be handled through backend services, but do I really need to create a service just to subscribe to the channel and forward the messages to my frontend app? Is this not an overkill?

The messages I am receiving are just time ticks (I need a trusted source of time), but I still don't want my API keys to leak out...

Is there any reasonably ok way for me to avoid standing up an intermediate service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep API keys secret when using client side Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847121/how-to-keep-api-keys-secret-when-using-client-side-javascript)

Comment: I don't think it would matter if your key leaks out though, It is supposed to be public,  You must have set a domain in PubNub just like you do for facebook auth, it will only allow requests from that domain and protect you from CSRF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly normal to have your PubNub publish and subscribe keys in client side code. If it is necessary to restrict who has the power to publish and subscribe (read/write) using those keys, the developer can enable PubNub Access Manager (PAM) in the admin panel. There are [PAM guides](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/tutorials/pubnub-access-manager?devrel_so=react-api-keys-and-intermediary-services) to get you started on controlling access.

Another point to consider is that your JavaScript PubNub connection can also be used as a trusted source of time. The JS SDK `time` call will get a 17 place precision unix timestamp from a PubNub node:

```
const pubnub = new PubNub({
  publishKey: 'your_free_pubnub_publish_key',
  subscribeKey: 'your_free_pubnub_subscribe_key'
});

let pojoDateObject;

pubnub.time().then((timetokenObject) => {
    pojoDateObject = new Date(+String(timetokenObject.timetoken).substring(0,13));
});
```