# How does Google protect the Maps Java script API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have starting looking into the classic newbie question of protecting a javascript API. Using API keys and such. I have also found the classic answer, that it can't be done. At least not completly secured.

Then I start thinking. When I use Google Maps javascript API, I provide a API key. Somehow I doubt that Google exposes there quite extensive API if API keys can be stolen simply by copying the key.

So How does google protect their API? How do I adapt this in my service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Google Maps secure their API Key? How to make something similar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256305/how-does-google-maps-secure-their-api-key-how-to-make-something-similar)