# How does Google Maps for Android v2 API key verification work?

Tags: android, security, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

I am wondering how does Google Maps Android v2 API key verification work? (I know how to request key and use it in an Android project.)

I am just interested in the method how it checks the app signature and use it to verify the requests on server side.

Is it possible to use a similar method to authorize users of my custom API, and be sure that nobody else use it, only through my signed app?

(This is a similar question, but it is about the browser version: [How does Google Maps secure their API Key? How to make something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256305/how-does-google-maps-secure-their-api-key-how-to-make-something-similar), it has nothing related to Android app signature)

Comment: Do you have an answer for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet...

Comment: Interested to get an answer on this too!