# Why my Google Maps usage was increased significantly when manually repeat QuotaService.RecordEvent

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've just configured HTTP referrers restriction for my Google Maps API key. I use map on my website. The problem is when I open it using Chrome and monitor network using Chrome DevTool, I found an interesting request

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent?XXXXXXX

Let's say the XXXXXXX was the rest of the URL which you can find it by yourself when did the monitoring like I did. So I just repeat this request and monitor my google map usage in API console and it was increased significantly.

The question is how could we prevent this attack?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue and I did repeat to quota service, finally quota was gone and google map showed grey background with "Oop!" word.

Do you report this to Google?