# How to hide google map api key in django before pushing it on github?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my google address api script which contains the api key

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key&libraries=places&callback=ActivatePlacesSearch">
```

I have used .env file in project directory to hide sensitive info from `settings.py` file. How can I use .env file to hide my api key from my template?

Comment: You can make it a setting, then pass it to the template in the context dictionary.

Comment: Please note, this key will be available through any browser dev tools, later after you deploy your project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define a variable in your `.env` file, for example:

```
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY="your_key"
```

Then in `myproject/settings.py`:

```
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY')
```

Then in your `views.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(request):
    context = {
        'api_key': settings.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
    }
    return render('template.html', context)
```

then you can access `api_key` in the template.

**Note** (thanks to trixn in the comments): Make sure the `.env` file is included in your `.gitignore` file so that it doesn't get checked into source control and leak your token. If you've used a standard `.gitignore` for Python, it should already be included.

Comment: I directly import the .env file in my views. So is there any demerit?

Comment: that is fine, but only accessing `.env` from settings and accessing settings from all other files is better practice. That way if you ever change where your environment variables come from, you only have to do it in `settings.py` rather than all over the place.

Comment: But then don't forget to ignore the `.env` file by adding it to the `.gitignore` file. Otherwise it would still be checked in and leaking your token.

Comment: I know this is old, but doesn't doing this expose the API key on the frontend?

Comment: @Kachinga you're right. Google has various checks for this by restricting the domain a key can be used on and what permissions a key has (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153734/do-i-need-to-hide-api-key-when-using-google-maps-js-api-if-so-how) for more info). Still I'd say it's good practice to keep your API keys out of version control as sometimes it does really matter and it makes the key a lot easier to find if the repository is public, plus you don't have to make a commit just to change the key if needed.