# vue autocomplete with google places - how to deal with api key exposure

Tags: vue.js, google-places-api

I've been looking through several ready-made vue components for autocompleting search using Google api. For instance [this one](https://github.com/gocanto/google-autocomplete) and [that one](https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete). And it seems to me that all of them let the user have an access directly to their Google Places API key (at least I can see it just in a page source of their demo sites).

Is it a right approach? How to deal with the fact that someone can take this key and quickly exceed the quota? Sorry for the naive question.

Answer (score 0):

seems the best solution for the frontend only is to restrict your API key, which can be easily [spoofed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411510/2747661). Alongside other solutions that Google suggests are [[link]](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table):

- Restrict your API keys
- Independent API key per app
- Delete API keys no longer needed
- Exercise caution when regenerating keys
- Monitor API key usage for anomalies

unless you could manage to implement a [backend API version](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) of it and query your backend API instead of Google API and then you could practice some solutions like rate limit on your backend API.

Comment: Thanks! I know that I use HTTP referrer to limit the use of my api key to my website only, but I just don't know how to 'set' it in the js code - or is it set automatically? Sorry for stupid questions

Comment: No problem, As Google Map Platform refers `The restriction becomes part of the API key,` and so it will be automatic in that sense. https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey