# How to protect laravel api route from outside GET request

Tags: laravel, vue.js, security, axios, get

I'm building the backend with laravel and then using Vue as front-end. Data is accessed over api calls using axios. Now I have this relatively simple task but I can't seem to find the proper solution. I want one of the routes to be easily consumable by Vue compoenents without the need to log in, however I don't want that route to be publicly available for anyone to use. I'm talking about the GET request and not the POST request with a CSRF token.

Let me add an example, here it is my route:

```
Route::get('MyFAQS',[\App\Http\Controllers\FaqController::class,'getQuestions']);
```

And the vue js:

```
        axios.get('api/MyFAQS').
        then(response => {
            this.FAQ = response.data;
            console.log(this.FAQ);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log("can not get FAQ: " + error)
        })
```

In this situation anyone can do also a GET request to `https://mywebsite.com/api/MyFAQS` and use my data on his website, how can I protect it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Google Maps secure their API Key? How to make something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2256305/283366)

Comment: @Phil not sure, i saw HTTP_REFERER, and i tried it and it works perfectly, but i think the referal it can be manipulated and sent back to my server

Comment: Without any other form of authentication / authorisation, you're in the realms of _"best effort"_

Comment: JavaScript is client code. In the absence of authentication, there is no way to "protect" a resource while still allowing client access to it.

Comment: The only way to get close to protecting a route without some sort of authentication is using request blocking from origins.  You can setup your back-end code to deny all requests from origins outside your desired origins such as your front-end.  This can easily be done in laravel with middleware.

Comment: @jgetner please go ahead and post an example